# Query in zend framework returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

i am running a custom query, no models involved, and it return an empty array.

Here is exact code that i use:

```
$query = 'SELECT SUM(open_diff) opens, SUM(revenue_diff) revenue, SUM(revenue) real_rev, manual_rev, SUM(opens) actual_opens 
                         FROM data.discrepancy
                         WHERE discrepancy_date >= \''.$dateStart.'\' AND discrepancy_date <= \''.$dateEnd.'\' AND  feed_id = '.$feeds[$i]["feed_id"];

                $db = Zend_Registry::get('db_slave');
                $stmt = $db->query($query);

               $records = $stmt->fetchAll();


Zend_Debug::dump($records); gets me this result:

array(1) {
[0] => array(5) {
["opens"] => NULL
["revenue"] => NULL
["real_rev"] => NULL
["manual_rev"] => NULL
["actual_opens"] => NULL
}
}
```

The data is in the database, and if i run that query directly in MySql, i have no problems.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will return null for sum() if there are no matching records.  What is the final query being executed (with the variables evaluated)?

I'd try running that in MySQL directly as well and you'll probably get the same results.

```
var_dump($dateStart, $dateEnd, $feeds[$i]['feed_id']);
```

See what those contain and you'll probably see the problem.

Comment: Right - seeing the actual type's of those values may be of use as well.

Comment: Variables evaluated just fine, i am running resulting queries directly in database and getting the results. Also, i removed SUMs and left real columns to select... still empty arrays

Comment: Here is actual evaluation:string(10) "2011-08-24"
string(10) "2011-08-24"
int(913)

Comment: Which database adapter are you using.  If you run $db->fetchAll($query) instead of query, fetchAll do you get any difference?

Comment: I'm using PDO. $db->fetchAll($query) did not make any difference, i even ran plain PHP in this action (mysql_connect... etc) - the same result. I am really confused at this point

Comment: I'd start removing the various where clauses and seeing which one is failing... Maybe the dates are a little off based on timezone discrepancies between the PHP connection and the MySQL shell connection? (grasping)

Comment: Hmmm, it works when i remove dates from the clause. I've tried to convert all dates to unix_timestamp - no result

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
$dbAbstract = new Zend_Db_Table_Abstract();

$select = $dbAbstract->select()
    ->from(
          array('a' => 'data.discrepancy'),
          array('SUM(open_diff) AS opens', 'SUM(revenue_diff) AS revenue'), 'SUM(revenue) AS real_rev', 'SUM(opens) AS actual_opens'
    )
    ->where('discrepancy_date >=?', $dateStart)
    ->where('discrepancy_date <=?', $dateEnd)
    ->where('feed_id =?', $feeds[$i]["feed_id"]);

$result = $dbAbstract->fetchAll($select);
```

Please remove AS that is not working